# Typescript mapped type, add optional modifier conditionally

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is it possible to make a mapped type property optional conditionally?

Consider this type

```js
type Definition {
  name: string,
  defaultImplementation?: ImplementationType
}
```

and a record of them:

```js
type DefinitionMap = Record<string, Definition>
```

I would like to make a mapped type that has an implementation that is optional if the input is provided, but the mapped type implementation required if it wasn't.

For an `DefinitionMap` like this

```js
{
  foo: { name: 'x' },
  bar: { name: 'y', defaultImplementation: { /*...*/ } }
}
```

I would like to have a mapped type like

```js
{
  foo: ImplementationType,
  bar?: ImplementationType
}
```

I've been trying to use conditionals and add `undefined` to the type, but that is not working.

```js
type ImplementationMap<T extends DefinitionMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { defaultImplementation: any }
    ? ImplementationType | undefined
    : ImplementationType
}
```

I know that the conditional branches behave how I want them to, but adding `undefined` doesn't actually make the field optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
type NonImplementedKeys<T extends DefinitionMap> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {defaultImplementation: ImplementationType} ? never : K}[keyof T]
type NiceIntersection<S, T> = {[K in keyof (S & T)]: (S & T)[K]}
type ImplementationMap<T extends DefinitionMap> = NiceIntersection<{
    [K in NonImplementedKeys<T>]: ImplementationType
}, {
    [K in keyof T]?: ImplementationType
}>
```

Example:

```
type DefinitionMapExample = {
  foo: { name: 'x' },
  bar: { name: 'y', defaultImplementation: { /*...*/ } }
}

// {foo: ImplementationType, bar?: ImplementationType | undefined}
type ImplementationMapExample = ImplementationMap<DefinitionMapExample>
```

The `NiceIntersection<S, T>` type is equivalent to a plain intersection type `S & T`, except it makes the result look like  `{foo: ..., bar?: ...}` instead of `{foo: ...} & {bar?: ...}`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSC2AHEBTeKB2AXMWCWA9hgCoCeiK0A3gL4CwAUFuZQCIoBmeGe+R0AXmqNo0DGHQAuaBCwAnbgHMANCOgATTmACuILAmRpMOPhgD80g6nTZchEi0b0mLaOy49TAWTCJB0ACUUYAI5dQAeWQUMFTdObl57AD5GRmYKaAA5IisjbBR1AGkUUghw4mgUAA8sTHUYdwTvXyT-KgBtQuhuaABrEoIOaGIAXWliTpHKmrqYKk0OHT1cmxN7SyRrYzsiMgoaaDMxFAA3FDloaUKadv7SQeGRtNdMvGAUWHy5CGDTcIBlZTDVpCDpdHp3B4ACn+0AAZMMAJRjaAw+FIybOdKUFbbZqIcrTWoYepxDyJIg+RAgrJvD5fH7AP5UNSiTrdDBZHKbPK1IolMrEJIo3G2Ux7FBOIEshiiNngzmQoajCxwHmrHYOChOFIMZ4ZRqeexUgCiVQkhjaag4BAI0ioYgkKGkAHIqi7oDRVLLoAAjMBye2OqTQF2kF1AhZLfTqvHrajQAD0ACoAHTp5OJz2epypBiJrNUG12tWGDXilhA-1yVWita7VwAH2g2hJ8QwBSxrjrmtN5p5-h7+PChopGD7FtQuqAA)

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming `DefinitionMap` should be `Record<string, Definition>` (instead of `Record<string, A>`).

Try this:

```ts
// Gets the keys of T whose values are assignable to V
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T]

type ImplementationMap<T extends DefinitionMap> =
    // A partial (all properties are optional) record for all the keys
    Partial<Record<keyof T, ImplementationType>> &
    // Require ImplementationType for all the keys that do not have defaultImplementation
    Record<KeysMatching<T, { defaultImplementation?: undefined }>, ImplementationType>

/*
Test is equivalent to
{
  foo: ImplementationType,
  bar?: ImplementationType,
  baz: ImplementationType
}
*/
type Test = ImplementationMap<{
  foo: { name: 'x' },
  bar: { name: 'y', defaultImplementation: { /*...*/ } },
  baz: { name: 'z', defaultImplementaiton: undefined }
}>
```

Comment: i like this answer than @kaya3's. much straightforward.

Comment: This does read much nicer.  But my real types are actually interesting generics themselves, so @kaya3's answer is more versatile.  They're really basically the same, expect for using Partial as a shortcut.

Comment: This utility is very useful in itself: `type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T]`. It allow for lots of advanced magic. Exactly what I needed!