# Conditionally apply ? modifier in mapped type per-property

Tags: typescript, modifier, mapped-types

From the TypeScript docs:

```
// Removes 'optional' attributes from a type's properties
type Concrete<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]-?: Type[Property];
};

type MaybeUser = {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
};
```

I know I can add the `?` modifier to **all** properties, what if I want to add it property by property based on a `extends` expression?

Something that would behave like this:

```
// Not valid TypeScript
type Optionalize<T> = {
   [P in keyof T](?: T[P] extends SomeInterface): T[P];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript mapped type, add optional modifier conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66928064/typescript-mapped-type-add-optional-modifier-conditionally)

Comment: I had thought it didn't, but reading it better it just might be.

Comment: It kind of did, but not fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32562

1. Extract the non matching props in a type, let's call it `NonMatching`
2. Extract the matching prop in a second type, say `Matching`
3. Intersect the two types using the `extends infer` technique

```
type TestType = {
  a: SomeInterface;
  b: string;
};

type Intersection<A, B> = A & B extends infer U
  ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] }
  : never;

type Matching<T, SomeInterface> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SomeInterface ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type NonMatching<T, SomeInterface> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SomeInterface ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

type DesiredOutcome = Intersection<
  Partial<Pick<TestType, Matching<TestType, SomeInterface>>>,
  Required<Pick<TestType, NonMatching<TestType, SomeInterface>>
>
```

`{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends SomeInterface ? K : never }` it's kind of a workaround to map every matching key to it's own *string literal type representation*, i.e. given `{ a: never, b: SomeInterface }` you get `{ b: 'b' }`, then using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) you get the *matching properties in the form of union of string literal types*