# Construct TypeScript type from array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have the following schema columns for a database table (used for Watermelon DB).

```js
const columns = [
  { name: "created_at", type: "number", isOptional: true },
  { name: "created_by", type: "string" },
  { name: "is_corrupt", type: "boolean", isOptional: true },
];
```

I would like to create a generic which will create the following type from the above example, how can I do that?

```js
type ExpectedInferredTypeFromColumns = {
  created_at: number | null;
  created_by: string;
  is_corrupt: boolean | null;
};
```

---

My attempt:

```js
type InferTypeFromColumns<T extends ReadonlyArray<Column>> = {
  [K in T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
    ? U extends { name: string }
      ? U["name"]
      : never
    : never]: T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
    ? U extends { type: "number"; isOptional: true }
      ? number | null
      : U extends { type: "number" }
      ? number
      : U extends { type: "string"; isOptional: true }
      ? string | null
      : U extends { type: "string" }
      ? string
      : U extends { type: "boolean"; isOptional: true }
      ? boolean | null
      : U extends { type: "boolean" }
      ? boolean
      : never
    : never;
};

type MyInferredType = InferTypeFromColumns<typeof columns>;
// Produces: => 
// type MyInferredType = {
//     created_at: string | number | boolean | null;
//     created_by: string | number | boolean | null;
//     is_corrupt: string | number | boolean | null;
// }
```

As you can see my attempt doesn't quite meet my `ExpectedInferredTypeFromColumns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2BXAtpGBeGBtAUDGA3jGAIbICmAXDAETABO5JU5AJgPrM0A0MUAngAcqtMCgBG5ejxgBLCAHlBUWeBLxqUeonIwAvtzyFiZEXUbM27cfxkDh1GtHqywAcxr7D+IqQqP5dlB6bWU7ITNxEBB4JjAZeSUVNQ0+bV0DHABdGBIIOHBoAG4cHHtdAGEYlDAMQiM-EWdXNxL8cscxZElpGAAfWmb3TwGaKJi4miNE5VVSeAB+anHYkjAcPVLymAAVCIBZEkFhejqCIxW45ejVsDaYIbdqR-uunuo3qRLNsoiYAEkwAAzKR7YQAMXoIGQVSQqAgAB4djByAAPFhgVj5ABKTFY4Hg-AAgiESPwEbCagA+KlnIxYADSclqOywn3oOTyMAZWAA5I1eVkstQweRDscpIy+eVBTkBgAKHm8mbJeaClHo8iY-JaHQwBbERDweAwD7kABuUgAlBstn8duRoHVASD6KLIdDKfCEeUQECCnDIFScAB6ABUv2Eu0dsEw53w+AYTBYHGYHwkUn6huN90TFhT1n4zy0LVzcggQRAIUQymuEzWWbEOdtYZDQA)

```ts
const columns = [
  { name: "created_at", type: "number", isOptional: true },
  { name: "created_by", type: "string" },
  { name: "is_corrupt", type: "boolean", isOptional: true },
] as const; // define as const so `columns[number]` gives precise type inference

type Column = {
  name: string;
  type: "number" | "string" | "boolean"
  isOptional?: boolean
}

type TypeMapper = {
  boolean: boolean;
  string: string;
  number: number;
}

// You need to create a union depending if `isOptional` is defined or not
type InferTypeFromColumns<T extends ReadonlyArray<Column>> = {
  [K in T[number] as K['name']]: TypeMapper[K['type']] | (K['isOptional'] extends true ? null : never)
}

type Test = InferTypeFromColumns<typeof columns>
/*
type Test = {
    created_at: number | null;
    created_by: string;
    is_corrupt: boolean | null;
}
*/
```

If you need to have the optional keys, you will need to do an intersection of the optional and required keys [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2BXAtpGBeGBtAUDGA3jGAIbICmAXDAETABO5JU5AJgPrM0A0MUAngAcqtMCgBG5ejxgBLCAHlBUWeBLxqUeonIwAvtzyFiZEXUbM27cfxkDh1GtHqywAcxr7D+IqQqP5dlB6bWU7ITNxEBB4JjAZeSUVNQ0+bV0DHABdGBIIOHBoAG4cHHtdAGEYlDAMQiM-EWdXNxL8cscxZElpGAAfWmb3TwGaKJi4miNE5VVSeAB+anHYkjAcPVLymAAVCIBZEkFhejqCIxW45ejVsDaYIbdqR-uunuo3qRLNsoiYACVyABHRCyRisACSYAAZlI9sIAGL0EDIKpIVAQAA8Oxg5AAHiwwKx8oCSKxwPB+ABBEIkfiYtE1AB8TLORiwAGk5LUdlhPvQcnkYBysAByGbJeainL4wnEtI6GALYjkABuUhg1BFosa0qy1Hh5EOxyknLF5T1Gy2fySc3UUNh9ENSJRjIx2NxBPIRJJTHJYEpNPodIZ1VQLLZ+E53N2fIkUkF+W1Ert8Glnrl+S0iuV2t1OQ+aoTS12ByOJzNootWRyAwAFMnFLMUunZd75dndMqxPB4JqVer6ABKK2-YQwKEsegQcjASWYqm8ABCrMwVJgADIYEuM+38q5HTAAKpGZVELAABRjAGtyPwQNDj-rj5ecpt8IXByUx7oduRoHUk5SDOc5zJigIgmCbAOnCEQuqiYaQJi5QPgU6KQEyvC2ikMFOnByIIehWIoY+CA1BALKlAA9AAVD+uz-rAmDnPg+AMEwLAcDYzxaC09xsRYnGcFAJb8v0xCIL24mIES5DQq4bD8XIEBBCAISIMoJaXGs4k9n2AwyawckKaw3w4DRVFAA):

```ts
type RequiredInferTypeFromColumns<T extends ReadonlyArray<Column>> = {
  [K in T[number] as K['isOptional'] extends true ? never : K['name']]: TypeMapper[K['type']]
}

type OptionalInferTypeFromColumns<T extends ReadonlyArray<Column>> = {
  [K in T[number] as K['isOptional'] extends true ? K['name'] : never]?: TypeMapper[K['type']] | null
}

type Intersection<A, B> = A & B extends infer U
  ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] }
  : never;

type Test = Intersection<RequiredInferTypeFromColumns<typeof columns>, OptionalInferTypeFromColumns<typeof columns>>
/*
type Test = {
    created_by: string;
    created_at?: number | null | undefined;
    is_corrupt?: boolean | null | undefined;
}
*/
```

This answer was inspired by this solution: [Conditionally apply ? modifier in mapped type per-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552360/conditionally-apply-modifier-in-mapped-type-per-property)

Comment: Thanks, I am struggling with one additional step, perhaps you could give a hint on how to solve. How would you also make those keys optional? ie desired output `type Test = { created_at?: number | null; created_by: string; is_corrupt?: boolean | null; }` Thanks!

Comment: See the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so by basically copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66501289/1376627) I was able to get a working solution

```js
const columns = [
  { name: "created_at", type: "number", isOptional: true },
  { name: "created_by", type: "string", isOptional: false },
  { name: "is_corrupt", type: "boolean", isOptional: true },
] as const;

type InferTypeFromColumns<P extends readonly unknown[]> = {
  [K in IndexKeys<P> as Name<P[K]>]: Type<P[K]>;
};
type IndexKeys<A extends readonly unknown[]> = Exclude<keyof A, keyof []>;
type Name<O> = O extends { name: infer N }
  ? N extends string
    ? N
    : never
  : never;
type Type<T> = T extends { type: "number"; isOptional: true }
  ? number | null
  : T extends { type: "number" }
  ? number
  : T extends { type: "string"; isOptional: true }
  ? string | null
  : T extends { type: "string" }
  ? string
  : T extends { type: "boolean"; isOptional: true }
  ? boolean | null
  : T extends { type: "boolean" }
  ? boolean
  : never;

type MyInferredType = InferTypeFromColumns<typeof columns>;
```