# Get type based on the selected keyof value

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type that maps to a database table where the keys are the column names:

```js
interface MyTable {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

And then I have another type that maps from a form field to the table row.

```js
interface MyTableMap<T> {
  columnName: keyof T;
  formFieldName: string;
  value: any;
}

// I want this to generate an error because 12345 is not a string based on the column name of "foo".
const first: MyTableMap<MyTable> = { columnName: "foo", value: 12345 };
```

In the example above I don't want to define `value: any` but rather have it be the type that it is supposed to be based on the value of `columnName`. I can't seem to figure out how to do this without passing a second generic. We know the key is "foo" so how can I tell TypeScript what the correct type for value should be?

Comment: I see where this is going, you should have a look at this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73387637/construct-typescript-type-from-array-of-objects/73389365#73389365) if you plan to do optional typings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a union of all field-value pairs. So for your example we should generate: `{ columnName: 'foo', value: string } | { columnName: 'bar', value: number }`

We can do this using a mapped type to generate the type for each field and then get the desired union indexing back into the mapped type:

```
type MyTableMap<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:{
        columnName: P;
        value: T[P];
    }
}[keyof T]

// Error
const bad: MyTableMap<MyTable> = { columnName: "foo", value: 12345 };
const ok: MyTableMap<MyTable> = { columnName: "foo", value: "12345" };
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AqcBGAbFAbwChlkYB7CgLmQGcwpQBzAblORzilpAFcAtjmjsAvsQlh0ABxQZs+CKjjSAPJgB8yALzISZMgG0ACslDIA1hHQUYyTAF1q+g64QU8gkADk4AiLTG7K6uAG5wngH2Jg7BBuKihlY2do4SAPTpyACiUFAUUMTuIAyccAAmtPK4BMpq1YpauoTI7p4CPn5RAESUFN0ANMjhkbQAjABMAMwALACsyKLsxaUUFlVYNUoqqg0ETXqtHl6+-rS9VIPDEXw9k7Nz3YusQA)

Comment: Much simpler than I expected, thank you!