# How to construct an object type from arbitrary number of smaller objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Would it by possible, in TypeScript, to create a function which will be used like this:

```js
foo(
  { key1: 'hello' },
  { key2: 5 },
  { key3: true },
)
```

and it would return a type like below?

```
{
  key1: string,
  key2: number,
  key3: boolean,
}
```

The function would ideally allow arbitrary number of arguments. This is something like an intersection of arbitrary number of types.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73387637/construct-typescript-type-from-array-of-objects) which asks for something similar, but they have the array of types declared `as const` in a variable.

I suspect that what I suggest is not possible but looking forward to be surprised.

Comment: Creating the function is trivial, but do you need the returned value to be strongly typed?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses a recursive type to dynamically compute an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) that represents the merged result object:

```
type Merge<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer V]
  ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } & Merge<V>
  : {};

function foo<T extends object[]>(...args: T): Merge<T>  {
  return Object.assign({}, ...args);
}
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5QCueA1ngPYDueA2gLoB8UAvFBtroSQwEs8AMwRQAqgBooAOjlDR8KADUmAKChQA-FADeUBgGkoQqBQghqwiUwBcEo0ygBfKADJYCZCmUsNUe11nAG41NWFyAGNgAWo8KGFqanRMHHxiKGoAIwArCGjmFgAKORkAQyQiezQASns4JFQ0Nj1-eAhgUnh4gHlc-OByoiIBRDwioOlSisQiGtDnMMi4omAoLA4EpImzCwBGewByAAsIABsz6kOXaX1zEAAmewBWG71dkABme2B4UmhnPM1Ms8KsoCBNolqDt7gcoCdzpdroDQiCwQAvSHbIFAA) with examples</sup>